# How can I check if a game has been used?

Tags: ps4

I bought the Uncharted: the Nathan Drake Collection on Amazon. Today I finally got it and I have a feeling that is has been used. Can I check somewhere if the disc is really new? It's the special edition and I am not sure if that one comes with foil.

Comment: What do you mean comes with foil?

Comment: Does it honestly matter if it is used? As long as the game disk is clean and relatively scratch free it shouldn't matter, unless it is one of those games with DLC codes, which the Nathan Drake Collection doesn't I believe.

Comment: @Vemonus I assume the OP meant the plastic wrap that is usually wrapped around a new physical games box.  Some exceptions to this are usually special edition games such as [Halo Wars Limited edition](http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/j7EAAOSwSv1XmDda/s-l300.jpg), which came in a tin-like case and I believe no plastic wrap.

Comment: @Jeremy I would check to see if you did order the game as new then, because Amazon always gives you the option to select from new and pre-owned games when you purchase something. If you selected pre-owned you may not be able to do anything about it since about 95% of the the pre-owned sellers are third parties not directly associated with Amazon.

Comment: I woulden't ask it, the problem is that I actually paid more for a "new" one.
https://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B013BMIOA6/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new - It's from Schnellundbilligwarenhandel, as you can see, I marked the "New option" and also in the description the seller states it's new.

Comment: @Jeremy I would get in contact with the distributor then, they might be able to help you get your DLC code if you did not receive it with your delivery.

Comment: @Jeremy Kind of a long shot, but from what I have been reading, Amazon would send you the code through email. Possibly check for an email from them with the code? Again long shot but it might solve that problem.

Comment: I misread the question when I wrote my answer, I thought it was about the special edition of Uncharted 4, not the Nathan Drake Collection! As far as I know, the SE of the Nathan Drake Collection doesn't have a DLC code and the three games should be on the disc, so if the game looks as new it won't really make a difference. I don't have it though so I don't know that for sure.

Comment: @Kodama you are right, checked wrong article about the DLC code... Still I paid extra money to get it new. Everything is okay, just the price isn't. Already contacted the distributor to try to get back the difference between a new and used copy.

Comment: So finally got almost the price difference back. Thanks to everbody who tried to help somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really check if a game has already been used, because if the user handles the disc with care there will be no visible change. You could check if the disc has scratches or fingerprints on it, but there is no other way to tell.

I have the EU special edition of Uncharted 4 and it wasn't wrapped in foil, but the outer box was closed with a round bit of tape if I remember correctly. The steelbook with the game was wrapped in foil though. I don't know if it's the same for the special edition of the Nathan Drake Collection though.

If a game comes with a DLC code, you should enter the code in the Playstation store to check if it is still valid. You don't need to redeem the code to check if it's valid if you cancel after entering the code but before redeeming it.

If the disc and package show no signs of use and the DLC has not been redeemed it wouldn't make a difference if someone had used it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While Amazon is likely to process an RMA at no charge to you if you submit one, it doesn't really matter if it's used or not (so long as everything is present and, in the case of software with an unlock key/bonus key, the key is unused). If everything is present, the disc works, all warranties and return policies are the same, and nothing is damaged, all that the repacked software is going to do is serve as a guarantee it's worked at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Discs are read only so the simple answer is you cant